# Receive data via POST via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, form-data

I'm trying to send data from a form to a PHP page, via AJAX, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, because I'm not able to echo these variables.

Here is the code of the page containing the form (some information has been hidden, but the code is working):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mt-5 col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <form id="adicionar_funcionario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="p-md-5">
            <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h2>
            <div style="float: left;" class="mt-5">
            <img src="../img/avatar.png" alt="Selecione uma imagem" <?php if(isset($errofoto)){echo "class='invalidoimg imgupload'";}else{echo "class='imgupload'";}?> id="imgfoto">
            <img src="../img/lixeira.png" id="lixeira" alt="Limpar foto" class="lixeira">
            <span class="erro"><?php if(isset($errofoto)){echo $errofoto;}?></span>
            </div>
                <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="ms-2 ms-lg-5 text-center col-5 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        <!-- SITUAÇÃO -->
                        <label for="situacao"> Situação: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-check form-switch">
                        <input id="situacao" name="situacao" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="mudarlabel(this.checked)" <?php if(isset($situacao)){echo "checked";}else{echo "checked";} ?>>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="situacao" id="labelsituacao"><?php if(isset($situacao)){echo "Ativado";}else{echo "Ativado";} ?></label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ms-lg-5 mt-4 col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="ms-lg-5 col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <!-- PRONOME -->
                        <label for="pronome"> Pronome </label>
                        <select id="pronome" <?php if(isset($erropronome)){echo "class='invalido form-select'";}else{echo "class='form-select'";}?> <?php if (isset($_POST['pronome'])){echo "value='".$_POST['pronome']."'";}?> name="pronome">
                            <?php
                                if ((isset($_POST['pronome']))){
                            ?>
                            <option selected><?php echo $_POST['pronome'];?></option>
                            <?php
                                }else{
                            ?>
                            <option selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
                            <?php
                                };
                            ?>
                            <option value="Ele/Dele">Ele/Dele</option>
                            <option value="Ela/Dela">Ela/Dela</option>
                            <option value="Todos">Todos</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="erro"><?php if(isset($erropronome)){echo $erropronome;}?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <!-- NOME COMPLETO -->
                        <label for="nomecompleto"> Nome completo </label>
                        <input type="text" id="nomecompleto" placeholder="Como consta no CPF..."<?php if(isset($erronomecompleto)){echo "class='invalido form-control'";}else{echo "class='form-control'";}?> <?php if (isset($_POST['nomecompleto'])){echo "value='".$_POST['nomecompleto']."'";}?> name="nomecompleto">
                        <span id="erronomecompleto" class="erro"><?php if(isset($erronomecompleto)){echo $erronomecompleto;}?></span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ms-lg-5 mt-4 col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="ms-lg-5 col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                        <!-- NOME SOCIAL -->
                        <label for="nomesocial"> Nome social </label>
                        <input type="text" id="nomesocial" placeholder="Gostaria de ser chamado(a)..." <?php if(isset($erronomesocial)){echo "class='invalido form-control'";}else{echo "class='form-control'";}?> <?php if (isset($_POST['nomesocial'])){echo "value='".$_POST['nomesocial']."'";}?> name="nomesocial">
                        <span class="erro"><?php if(isset($erronomesocial)){echo $erronomesocial;}?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                        <!-- NOME -->
                        <label for="nomeartistico"> Nome Artístico </label>
                        <input type="text" id="nomeartistico" placeholder="Irá aparecer nos créditos..." <?php if(isset($erronomeartistico)){echo "class='invalido form-control'";}else{echo "class='form-control'";}?> <?php if (isset($_POST['nomeartistico'])){echo "value='".$_POST['nomeartistico']."'";}?> name="nomeartistico">
                        <span class="erro"><?php if(isset($erronomeartistico)){echo $erronomeartistico;}?></span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <input accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg" type="file" id="foto" name="foto">
                    <input type="text" id="removerfoto" name="removerfoto">
                    <div class="form-group text-center">

                        <button id="criar" type="submit" class="mt-5 botao">Criar</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal hide fade" id="anexar_documentos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Documentacao" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="TituloModalLongoExemplo">Anexar documentos</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
   <h6 class="ms-3 mt-2"><b><i>Os arquivos precisam ser no formato jpg, png ou pdf e ter, no máximo, 2 MB</i></b></h6>
      <div id="anexos" class="modal-body">
        
      Escolha um regime, um cargo e um nível para anexar os documentos
        
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="../bootstrap/_bootstrap/js/enviar_formulario_adicionar_funcionario.js"></script>
</body>
</htlm>
```

Here is the AJAX code, being called as enviar_formulario_adicionar_funcionario.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#criar").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var dados = new FormData(document.getElementById("adicionar_funcionario"));
        $.ajax({
            url: '../utilities/criarfuncionario.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {
                data: dados
            },
            success: function(resultado){
                alert(resultado.erronomecompleto);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And here is the page being sent the data (again some data was removed as it was not relevant to the problem):

```
<?php

if (((isset($_POST['nomecompleto'])) || (isset($_POST['nomesocial'])) || 
(isset($_POST['nomeartistico'])) || (isset($_POST['telefone'])) || 
(isset($_POST['rg'])) || (isset($_POST['cpf'])) || (isset($_POST['email'])) || 
(isset($_POST['datanasc'])) || (isset($_POST['endereco'])) || 
(isset($_POST['bairro'])) || (isset($_POST['complemento'])) || 
(isset($_POST['cidade'])) || (isset($_POST['cep'])) || 
(isset($_POST['datacontratacao'])) || (isset($_POST['cargo'])) || 
(isset($_POST['projeto'])) || (isset($_POST['datasaida'])) || 
(isset($_POST['regime'])) || (isset($_POST['telefone'])) || 
(isset($_FILES['foto'])) || (isset($_POST['uf'])) || 
(isset($_POST['numero'])) || (isset($_POST['inicio_ferias'])) || 
(isset($_POST['fim_ferias']))) && 
(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'cadastro_convite') == false)){

    echo json_encode(array ('erronomecompleto' => 'Passei aqui'));

    $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $query_campo_obrigatorio = "SELECT * FROM campo_obrigatorio";
    $campo_obrigatorio_banco = $conn->prepare($query_campo_obrigatorio);
    $campo_obrigatorio_banco->execute();

    while($campo_obrigatorio = $campo_obrigatorio_banco->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        if($campo_obrigatorio['campo_nomecompleto'] == '1'){
            if((empty($dados['nomecompleto'])) || (str_replace(" ", "", $dados['nomecompleto']) == "")){
                $erronomecompleto = 'Preencha este campo';
            }
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' \pL]*$/u", limpapost($dados['nomecompleto']))){
                $erronomecompleto = "Apenas letra e espaços em branco neste campo";
            }else{
                $nomecompleto = limpapost($dados['nomecompleto']);
            }
        }else{
            if((empty($dados['nomecompleto'])) || (str_replace(" ", "", $dados['nomecompleto']) == "")){
                $nomecompleto = "";
            }
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' \pL]*$/u", limpapost($dados['nomecompleto']))){
                $erronomecompleto = "Apenas letra e espaços em branco neste campo";
            }else{
                $nomecompleto = limpapost($dados['nomecompleto']);
            }
        }
```

When I put the echo json_encode inside the IF conditions, I don't get a response, however, if I put it outside the IF conditions, I get the return "Passei aqui".

So I came to the conclusion that my $POST['anything'] is probably not getting anything.

I also tried to pass a value to any field and send the data (to see if it entered the IF conditions), however, I didn't get a return.

I apologize in advance, as I am new to this subject.

Comment: You have a lot of data that you're checking in that if block. You should get into that block if any of the isset checks pass, but maybe it's not passing `(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'cadastro_convite') == FALSE)`. You'll need to do some troubleshooting to find out. `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` before your `if` block to see what they contain.

Comment: I think your `data` property is wrong, don't create an object, just pass your formData: `data: dados`.

Comment: aynber thanks for the tip. I will try how I can do this.

Comment: azeós even doing what you asked, the error persists.

Comment: @aynber when I give a var_dump($_POST) it is returning all the variables that I send through AJAX. I did this by removing the dataType and leaving only alert(result)

Comment: Does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` return what you think it does?